# Selecting the values of the first row in pandas' DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame

```
                  AAPL         F       IBM
    Date            
    2016-05-02  46.536664   13.62   143.881476
    2016-05-03  47.302004   13.43   142.752373
    2016-05-04  46.810001   13.31   142.871221
    2016-05-05  46.619999   13.32   145.070003
    2016-05-06  46.360000   13.44   147.289993
```

I´d like to divide each column by the value of the first row and the multiply by 100. After the calculation, the first 2 rows should look like this:

```
                AAPL          F        IBM
    Date
    2016-05-02  100          100       100
    2016-05-03  101.63       98.60     99.21
```

I'm struggling, but I can't get it. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this:

```
df /= df.iloc[0]/100
```

or

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x/x.iloc[0]*100)
```

Test:

```
In [51]: df
Out[51]:
                 AAPL      F         IBM
Date
2016-05-02  46.536664  13.62  143.881476
2016-05-03  47.302004  13.43  142.752373
2016-05-04  46.810001  13.31  142.871221
2016-05-05  46.619999  13.32  145.070003
2016-05-06  46.360000  13.44  147.289993
```

Output:

```
In [63]: df /= df.iloc[0]/100

In [64]: df
Out[64]:
                  AAPL           F         IBM
Date
2016-05-02  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000
2016-05-03  101.644596   98.604993   99.215255
2016-05-04  100.587358   97.723935   99.297856
2016-05-05  100.179074   97.797357  100.826046
2016-05-06   99.620377   98.678414  102.368976
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I get the following message:

TypeError: ("cannot do index indexing on <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>", 'occurred at index AAPL')

Comment: @vsoler, i've updated my answer - changed `.loc` to `.iloc` - it should work